# Deploying Clojure apps with Leiningen

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

This is my project.clj file so far:

```
(defproject raj "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]
  :keep-non-project-classes true
  :main raj.core)
```

And my core.clj file:

```
(ns raj.core
  (:use raj.core))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "Hello World!!!"))
```

`lein run -m raj.core` displays the Hello World message just fine. So next I try `lein uberjar` and get

```
Compiling raj.core
Compilation succeeded.
Created C:\Users\bobjones\IdeaProjects\raj/raj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including raj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including clojure-1.3.0.jar
Created C:\Users\bobjones\IdeaProjects\raj/raj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

Everything seems to be going well so far, so I try `java -jar raj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`, and I receive

```
Error: Could not find or load main class raj.core
```

What would I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add a `:gen-class` declaration to the `raj.core` namespace:

```
(ns raj.core
  (:use raj.core)
  (:gen-class))
```