# Clojure REPL not launching at Windows command prompt

Tags: java, emacs, clojure, classpath, read-eval-print-loop

I have placed the clojure-1.4.0.jar path (C:\clojure-1.4.0\clojure-1.4.0.jar) in my CLASSPATH environment variable. Now when I try to launch the REPL from the command line with the following code:

> `java -cp clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main`

I get an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main
```

It used to work before I set up emacs. Any ideas.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628753/deploying-clojure-apps-with-leiningen

Comment: its actually not 'cos this is not to deploy an app but to launch the REPL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either add clojure jar file to `CLASSPATH` environment variable:

```
/some/where % CLASSPATH=/tmp/clojure-1.4.0.jar java clojure.main
```

or specify it directly in `java` arguments:

```
/some/where % java -cp /tmp/clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main
```

Setting `CLASSPATH` variable and providing `-cp` argument to `java` command at the same time is pointless, because `-cp` argument overrides `CLASSPATH` completely. This is the cause of your problem: you seem to be invoking `java` command not from the directory where `clojure-1.4.0.jar` is located, so `-cp clojure-1.4.0.jar` switch makes `java` program try to locate `clojure-1.4.0.jar` in the current directory and ignore `CLASSPATH`. Since there is no `clojure-1.4.0.jar` in the current directory, the command fails.